# How do I invert the colors on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, color

As a prank someone has inverted the colors on my iPhone. Black is white, blue is orange, etc. How do I get my phone back to normal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Settings -> General -> Accessibility and set "White on Black" to Off.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I wonder what's the real point of this feature though (probably not pranks)...

Comment: Inverting the colors helps people with poor eyesight.

Comment: There's also a shortcut (disabled by default) to switch between the normal and inverted displays, which is pressing the Home button 3 times in a row.